# Imagem com intervalo de tempo - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba

Preciso atribuir uma imagem que apareça a cada 1 hora no EXCEL, como?!
Provavelmente será necessário utilizar o VBA. Mas não sou muito familiarizado.

E que feche sozinha após 1 minuto.

Comment: Onde a imagem está localizada? Na web ou no computador? Se no computador, mesma pasta do arquivo Excel?

Comment: Por favor, leia o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/75104), [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas) e [Seja mais específico na pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1481/75104)

Comment: Perdão, eu fiz pelo celular no meio da linha de produção na empresa.
É, ela vai está localizada no computador. Quero que apareça uma imagem e fique durante 1 minuto, nesse 1 minuto é pros colaboradores fazerem exercícios de alongamento para a ergonomia, etc...

Comment: Melhor, tem como por em intervalos específicos de horário? Em vez de ser de 1 em 1 hora, pois tem intervalos, horário de almoço, etc... Teria como por horas específicas? 10:00 12:00 14:00, etc... Deu 10:00, pum, aparece a imagem que vai ficar durante 1 minuto pra lembrar sobre a ergonomia.

Comment: Procure por [agendar tarefas em VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17632087/7690982) e depois como criar um [Sub para mostrar imagens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41230570/7690982).

Comment: Minha sugestão é que você utilize o Agendador de Tarefas do Windows para fazer essa tarefa. Você pode utilizá-lo para agendar ações para serem executadas de tempos em tempos. Na configuração da ação, você pode pedir para exibir uma imagem.

Comment: Fernando, poderia criar o exemplo do agendador  de tarefas? Estou desde ontem pesquisando e apenas falhei até o momento :/

Comment: Fernando? Ainda está ai? Poderia dar o exemplo? kk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Agendador

Use este código VBA para agendar tarefas no horário desejado:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    '-- Roda os Subs ou funções no horário agendado.
    'Deve ser colodado em EstaPastadeTrabalho

    Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:00:00"), "mostrarImagem"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("12:00:00"), "mostrarImagem"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:00:00"), "mostrarImagem"
End Sub
```

### Mostrar Imagem

Este é usado para mostrar a imagem e o caminho da imagem deve ser escrito em `strPath`

```
Sub mostrarImagem()
    Debug.Print "mostrarImagem() rodou as " & Time
    On Error GoTo 0
    'INSERIR O CAMINHO DA IMAGEM AQUI
    strPath = "C:/Caminho/do/arquivo/de/Imagem.jpg"
Inicio:
    If Dir(strPath) <> "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert (strPath)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
        Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
        ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
        ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
        ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
        Application.OnTime Now() + CDate("00:01:00"), "fecharImagem"
    Else
        MsgBox "A imagem não pôde ser carregada - Escolha a imagem."
        strPath = EscolherImagem
        GoTo Inicio
    End If
End Sub
```

### Escolher a imagem

Esta é uma função para lidar com erro, caso o caminho da imagem não encontre nada.

```
Public Function EscolherImagem() As String
    'Créditos: http://software-solutions-online.com/excel-vba-open-file-dialog/
    Dim intChoice As Long
    Dim strPath As String

    'only allow the user to select one file
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
    'make the file dialog visible to the user
    intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
    'determine what choice the user made
    If intChoice <> 0 Then
        'get the file path selected by the user
        strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
                  msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
        'print the file path to sheet 1
        EscolherImagem = strPath
    End If
End Function
```

### Fechar imagem

Este Sub é chamado 1 minuto após inserir a imagem.

```
Sub fecharImagem()
    'Sub agendado irá rodar por 1 minuto
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Delete
    Application.DisplayFullScreen = False
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
    ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
    ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = True
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Debug.Print "mostrarImagem() parou as " & Time
End Sub
```